# DokuWiki add page in admin section

Tags: php, dokuwiki

I'd like to add a page to DokuWiki's admin section (https://my.url/doku.php?id=index&do=admin)

How can I do this? I searched all over the internet and can't find any solution.
Maybe someone is familiar with DW here.

P.s. (It should be obvious that only admins should be able to see the page and it contends.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's just a regular wiki page:

1. Create your page.
2. Restrict access to your page using DokuWiki's ACL management.
3. Edit admin.txt for your language(s), e.g. "inc/lang/en/admin.txt" to add a link to your page, e.g:

   ====== Administration ======

   [[myspace:mypage|My Page]]

   Below you can find a list of administrative tasks available in DokuWiki.